# How do I preserve physical sizes between different iThings in Open GL?

Tags: iphone, ipad, opengl-es, screen-resolution, retina-display

I woke up one day recently realizing that we iOS developers now have a small fleet of different screen-sizes/resolutions to accommodate. This table illustrates the screen specs of currently deployed iOS devices:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density

Very handy. Now here's the connundrum:

I build a simple Open GL view onto my iPad2. My code Is making an OpenGL viewport of the 
ordinary pixel dimensions of iPhone/Pad (320x480, 768x1024). I draw a white rectangle into this thing. I make it 200px wide. It's nice. Good ol' iPad.

I compile the same code (which is auto detecting screen dimensions) into my iPhone4. My white rectangle is not the same width as it was on the pad. Fair enough. I know that the actual pixel dimensions of the iPhone4 are 640x960, and those of the iPad are 768x1024, taking into account ppi of each device.

Dividing 768/640 I arrive at the nice scaling factor 1.2, which I then multiply by 200 for the width of my test rectangle and recompile for iPhone4... Arrrgh... it *almost* works. The rectangle is just a few pixels less wide than its iPad counterpart.

Can anyone point out a mistake in my reasoning? I want to have the ability to mark a displayable object as 'screen-independent' to preserve it's *physical* dimensions between iThings. Write once run anywhere. Yeah right.

I'm building a game, and of course that damnably wonderful iPad3 has a new resolution. I'm trying to abstract out as many of the possible resolution pitfalls as I can. I probably will not have the opportunity to test my app on an iPad3 before release. Is anyone else in this same boat?

Comment: I wouldn't scale it on the factor of dividing the bigger screen size by the small screen size. I'd do it with the factor of dividing PPI. However, I wouldn't worry about the physical size, as long as the proportions are good, it should be enough (unless you NEED the physical size to remain unchanged between devices, like on a ruler app)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem. The solution I explained in my last post in completely specious.

OpenGL, when drawing my test rectangle, does not care about the pixel resolution. It only cares about the coordinate system you feed it. Like many of you no doubt, I'm using the convenient 320x480 / 768x1024 dimensions for the coordinate systems in OpenGL for Phone/Pad.

The thing I was missing is that 200 'OpenGL-land' units in the iPhone[320/480] system is different than 200 units in the iPad[768/1024] system *not* because of screen resolution differences, but because the ratio of 320/760 (or equivalently, 480/1024) is different than the ratios of screen-widths or screen-heights of the Phone/Pad. I got out a ruler and measured the dimensions for myself because I couldn't find authoritative, credible numbers on the web.

iPhone screen width: 5.05 cm
iPad screen width: 14.8 cm

You can easily see that 5.05/14.8 is different from 320/768.

At any rate, the 'true' ratio of cm to OpenGL units on the iPhone is 5.05/320, and the iPad equivalent is 14.8/768.

The scaling factor between the two is x:

14.8/768 = x(5.05/320)

0.01927083333333 = x*0.01578125

= 1.221 (nearest thousandth)

So I went back into my iPhone code and now I sized my test rectangle to 1.221*200 wide and left my test rectangle to 200 in my iPad code. Recompiled both. *This* time, my white test rectangle is exactly the same width on both my iPad2 and my iPhone4.

OpenGL is not paying attention to the pixel density. It's paying attention to its coordinate system. That's why this technique works. Maybe it's a little crazy to preserve physical dimensions exactly, but I can sleep a little easier knowing that there's a solution if I need it.

Millenium Falcon,
   Alex